# Связь один ко многим в Entity Framework с таблицей пользователей ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

Разбираюсь с ASP.NET Identity. Она создает свою таблицу пользователей. И мне нужно связать связать эту таблицу с таблицей статей.

Смотрел примеры [тут](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes/) и [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.3.php).

Получилось так:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
public virtual ICollection<article> Articles { get; set; }

public ApplicationUser()
{
Articles = new List<article>();
}

public override string ToString()
{
return Name;
}

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<applicationuser>
{
public ApplicationDbContext()

: base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false){}

public DbSet<article> Articles { get; set; }

public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
}

public class Article
{
// ID статьи
public int Id { get; set; }
// название статьи
public string Name { get; set; }
// описание статьи
public string Description { get; set; }
public string? UserId { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Не совсем понял, для чего нужно?

```
public override string ToString()
    {
    return Name;
    }
```

и что он должен возвращать?

И такой вопрос, если у меня тут правильно сделано и я захочу создать к примеру таблицу комментариев привязанную к пользователям то мне так же по аналогии добавить нужные поля в ApplicationUser? или нужно что-то еще указывать Entity Framework'у если используем два или более внешних ключа?

Comment: Все разобрался, с первой частью
этот код не нужен

public override string ToString()

    {

    return Name;

    }

Но на последний вопрос пока ответа не нашел

Comment: На последний вопрос так же разобрался, работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Вам за ответ на мой вопрос). попробовал создать еще таблицу и связь с пользователем, достаточно вроде как добавить

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
 public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Правда еще не знаю как это отразиться на работе в дальнейшем.(типа доступа к данным пользователя и тд).